# How to add Toolbar on right side in Xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, cross-platform, mobile-application

How do I add a hamburger menu on the right side navigation bar in Xamarin forms?

[image]

Comment: Are you want tool bar or hamburger ?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your xaml

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Order="Secondary" Priority="0" Text="Item 1" Command="{Binding Item1_Command}"/>
    <ToolbarItem Order="Secondary" Priority="0" Text="Item 2" Command="{Binding Item2_Command}"/>
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

Comment: how to create this menu frame?

Comment: Sorry not sure what you are asking "menu frame". if you please the above in your xaml just below <ContentPage ....> you should get the hamburger menu with "Item 1" and "Item 2"